# How to use Javascript so that every time I click a image, its adds a new image below the item clicked on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, if the title didn't make sense to you, I will go into some more detail here. First, I will show you the document I would like to add this to.

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div style="text-align:center"><!-- This is where the image that will be clicked on will be placed.--> </div>
  <div style="text-align:center"><!-- This is where I want the new images to show up. --></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I hope that gives you a basic idea of what I would like this to do, but if not I will explain it further now...
So each time 'image1' is clicked on, a new image is placed below it this is idenfinate and will always be 'image2'. How would I succeed with this.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean a lightbox type of thing where the image below is bigger and shows a description? Like, http://cheesecakebb.org/index.php?action=viewgallery

Comment: Writing code would be a good start. We're here to help, not do your job for you.

Comment: No, like when you click a button. A completely different image will be added to the page, below where you have clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you started:

When you click inside `main`, a new image is appended into `new`.

```js
$('#main').click(function() {
  $('#new').append("<img src='http://placehold.it/140x100' />");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="text-align:center" id='main'>
  <img src='http://placehold.it/350x150' />
</div>
<div style="text-align:center" id='new'></div>
```